# Internet conection problem during updating?

Tags: networking

I am new to Ubuntu. I was connected to internet through cable and I my browser was working. I wanted to update my Ubuntu but it was not updating instead system asked user-name and password (my broadband connection login)

My browser is working but system is always saying check internet connection. 
How to update and download latest software through update manager.

Comment: Are you on proxy connection? Could you post terminal output of `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: yea i updated my ubuntu through terminal, but why through ubuntu software centre is not installing software’s like vlc player, adobe flash player etc..
what is the problem ?
can i install through terminal

Comment: You need to explain better this issue, it's impossible to help you without understanding what's going on. Ask a question explaining properly what is happening when trying to install software through USC. USC will ask you your root password not your broadband connection password, and yes everything can be installed through terminal too.

Answer (score 1):

You are obviously connecting to Internet using an internet proxy that also requires authentication, this is configured on your browser only and won't work on package manager by default.

Run the following in a terminal and you will be able to update your Ubuntu.

```
export http_proxy=http://yourproxyaddress:proxyport
http_proxy=http://username:password@yourproxyaddress:proxyport
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

hope this helps you :)

Note: this will only set a Temp apt proxy. for details on apt and how to set it permanently; refer to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto

Comment: This will plainly not work. If he is in a root terminal sudo is a) not needed b) plainly wrong, because it will set the environment variable in a subshell, and the following commands will be unable to see it, and c) wrong, because sudo zaps all environment variables anyway before calling the command.

Comment: @Romano, updated (and it works with me :) )

Comment: Yes, now it works.